# Android navigation drawer exits on back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer in my MainActivity.java to switch fragments and I am also extending my MainActivity to the other activities in my app. Now the problem is that, when I press back button during I am on fragment, the app suddenly exits without any notification. And if I use OnBackPressed in my MainActivity it is bydefault implemented to the other activities extending main activity too and when I press back button to any of that acivity it asks me first for confirmation and then comes back to previous activity or frag. Need a solution to avoid this. I want to set onbackpessed or anything that shows dialogue or asks for confirmation to exit app on fragments only but dont know howto do.

Or any help regarding fragment back stacking to open a fixed fragment on back button pressed is welcomed if it tells how to change the title of hence opened fragment too.

Answer (score 0):

call **onBackPressed()** in that activity in which you have put all fragment or main activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            //Display your dialog here
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

**Other solution**

```
@Override


    public void onBackPressed() {
            if (slidingMenu.isMenuShowing()) {
                slidingMenu.toggle(true);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
                //Display your dialog
            }
        }
```

This is works for me.

Comment: Are mere bhai, I already tried it and mentioned in querry too. But I dont want onback pressed or other activities extending the main activity.

Comment: But in your question you wrote " I want to set onbackpessed or anything that shows dialogue or asks for confirmation to exit app"

Comment: yeah but for fragments in navigation drawer only, not for activities extending MainActivity.